# RHEL: iscsiadm is not able to login in any port except 3260

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, iscsi, open-iscsi

Discovery is successful:

```
[root@ncdqd0110 iqn.11351.com.xxx:AAA]# iscsiadm -m discoverydb -t sendtargets -p 127.0.0.1:54541 --discover
127.0.0.1:54541,-1 iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA
```

Login is failing:

```
[root@ncdqd0110 ~]# iscsiadm --mode node --target iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA --portal 127.0.0.1:54541 --login
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA, portal: 127.0.0.1,54541] (multiple)
**iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA, portal: 127.0.0.1,54541].**
**iscsiadm: initiator reported error (8 - connection timed out)**
iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals
```

This is happening in **Redhat v7.0**. In Suse its working fine.

Few results of commands are given below:

```
[root@ncdqd0110 iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA]# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.31.224.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno16780032
10.31.224.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 eno16780032
```

```
[root@ncdqd0110 ~]# ip route show
default via 10.31.224.1 dev eno16780032  proto static  metric 1024
10.31.224.0/22 dev eno16780032  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.31.227.110
# BEGIN RECORD 6.2.0.873-21
node.name = iqn.2495.com.emc:BBB
node.tpgt = -1
node.startup = automatic
node.leading_login = No
iface.net_ifacename = eno16780032
iface.iscsi_ifacename = default
iface.transport_name = tcp
iface.vlan_id = 0
iface.vlan_priority = 0
iface.iface_num = 0
iface.mtu = 0
iface.port = 0
iface.tos = 0
iface.ttl = 0
iface.tcp_wsf = 0
iface.tcp_timer_scale = 0
iface.def_task_mgmt_timeout = 0
iface.erl = 0
iface.max_receive_data_len = 0
iface.first_burst_len = 0
iface.max_outstanding_r2t = 0
iface.max_burst_len = 0
node.discovery_address = 127.0.0.1
node.discovery_port = 54541
node.discovery_type = send_targets
node.session.initial_cmdsn = 0
node.session.initial_login_retry_max = 8
node.session.xmit_thread_priority = -20
node.session.cmds_max = 128
node.session.queue_depth = 32
node.session.nr_sessions = 1
node.session.auth.authmethod = None
node.session.timeo.replacement_timeout = 120
node.session.err_timeo.abort_timeout = 15
node.session.err_timeo.lu_reset_timeout = 30
node.session.err_timeo.tgt_reset_timeout = 30
node.session.err_timeo.host_reset_timeout = 60
node.session.iscsi.FastAbort = Yes
node.session.iscsi.InitialR2T = No
node.session.iscsi.ImmediateData = Yes
node.session.iscsi.FirstBurstLength = 262144
node.session.iscsi.MaxBurstLength = 16776192
node.session.iscsi.DefaultTime2Retain = 0
node.session.iscsi.DefaultTime2Wait = 2
node.session.iscsi.MaxConnections = 1
node.session.iscsi.MaxOutstandingR2T = 1
node.session.iscsi.ERL = 0
node.conn[0].address = 127.0.0.1
node.conn[0].port = 54541
node.conn[0].startup = manual
node.conn[0].tcp.window_size = 524288
node.conn[0].tcp.type_of_service = 0
node.conn[0].timeo.logout_timeout = 15
node.conn[0].timeo.login_timeout = 15
node.conn[0].timeo.auth_timeout = 45
node.conn[0].timeo.noop_out_interval = 5
node.conn[0].timeo.noop_out_timeout = 5
node.conn[0].iscsi.MaxXmitDataSegmentLength = 0
node.conn[0].iscsi.MaxRecvDataSegmentLength = 262144
node.conn[0].iscsi.HeaderDigest = None
node.conn[0].iscsi.IFMarker = No
node.conn[0].iscsi.OFMarker = No
# END RECORD
```

If any one know regarding this issue please let me know, how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an SELinux policy choice. The discovery session is running within iscsiadm, but iscsid is restricted in which ports it can connect to.

One option is to use the audit2why/audit2allow utils from policycoreutils to create a local policy module, extending the default system SELinux policy to allow this.